# Docusaurus v2 nav link actions on home page and doc pages

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I have various section on my docusaurus homepage, and from the top navigation bar I am able to `scrollTo` intended sections using below code by checking `window.location.pathname==='/'`.

```
let navLink = document.querySelectorAll('nav .navbar__link');
if(navLink) {
  navLink.forEach(function(link) {
      link.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let selectedSection = e.currentTarget.textContent.toLowerCase();
        if(window.location.pathname === '/') {
          window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(`#anchor-${selectedSection}-section`).offsetTop - 100);
        }
      })
  })
}
```

Which is working fine when I am on home page.

After coming back (routing) to home page from docs page by clicking on `Home` nav link, the `scrollTo` method doesn't work and I am straightaway routed to docs path instead of scrolling to one of the home sections. Although I am checking for `window.location.pathname === '/'` the code doesn't execute.

Can someone help me figure out what is happening behind the scenes of routing while clicking from docs pages.

Note: I have written the above script on `index.js` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Created a new page called home.js

Step 2 : updated the docusaurus.config.js link object from `/` to `/home`

`{ to: '/home', label: "Home", position: 'left'}`

Step 3: inside `home.js` added the redirect functionality to redirect to "/" which solved my actual issue.